# android ListView black line at the header and bottom in RelativeLayout

Tags: android-layout, listview

**Please healp me to remove the black line at the header and bottom. i also attach my xml for your reference. Thank you very much.**
I can not post image so please refer link below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM5p0.png]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRemind"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wood">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        style="@style/NavBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            style="@style/NavBarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnShare"
            style="@style/NavBarShareBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        style="@style/NavBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            style="@style/NavBarBackBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">

        <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: 1 - Your layout is overcomplicated by the use of uselesee containers. 2 - It's easy to remove the upper and lower shadows.

Comment: Thanks man for the keyword to resolve the issue :)

Comment: It's `yourListView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);`

Comment: yes, from your 1st comment and the keyword 'shadow' I found the solution :) solution

Comment: Faaaaaaaaantastic... Thumbs up!! Now, you have to simplify your layout. I didn't post it as an answer, since it would be off-topic. But I highly recommend a design optimization.